# how to make my website visible to everyone

Tags: web

I have created a website and it's working at my local machine. I want to make it public on web so that other can also use the same.  Please can you explain me step by step what I need to do?

Comment: Look up "website hosting".  Pick a host.  Move your website there.  Purchase a domain name.  Hook up the domain name to your website location.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking how web hosting works, and not anything to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to purchase website hosting, from there you'll get ftp details ie:-
Host name
Username
Password
Then you have to get connected to your server, for that you have to download Filezilla(https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client). 
On right hand side, it'll show you "Not connected to any server"
Panel where you have to add above details ie hostname, username and password will be shown like this:-
[image]

Once you get connected, it'll show a list of files on the right hand side where it says "Not connected to any server". There you have to look for root directory:-
Name of root directory can be:-
www
public_html
htdocs
These are the standard name, if you don't find such name, then contact your hosting company.
If everything goes well, upload your files to root directory.

**UPDATED**
You can follow these steps:-
[image]
Above image is of 3000X3000 resolution, so you can view this image in next tab to get the contents clearly

Comment: how to purchase website hosting?

Comment: I have added an image. I hope it'll help you.